# Dynamo/ Revit Clash Detection

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, bim

I'm new here, so I was trying out the Dynamo script for clash detection in Revit from -> (https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Construction-Dynamoite-Explode-Productivity-Dynamo-2016)

But there seems to be an issue where the 'Element.Create 3D Cropped view' node returns a Function and therefore is unable to pass into the 'element' port of 'Element.SetParameterByName' node. Same for the 'List.FilterByBoolMask' node which returns a list and unable to pass into the 'value' port.

**Main Graph**
[Warning: Element.SetParameterByName expects argument type(s) (Element, string, var), but was called with (Function, string, var[]).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blqYa.png)

**Element.Create 3D Cropped view**
[This is the 'Element.Create 3D Cropped view' node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXdQc.png)

I'm not sure what the issue is. What should I do to fix this? Thank you for you help!

Comment: I just checked and see that Dieter, the author of the AU class, is still at Autodesk, so I can ask him for advice for you. Furthermore, I suggest you raise this issue in the [DynamoBIM discussion forum](https://forum.dynamobim.com), where more of your peers may see it.